# How to do an OR query in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to limit access to certain categories to users of certain organisations only.

```
User
User_id, Username, Organisation_id

Organisation
Organisation_id, Org_name

Category
Category_id, Cat_name


Category_Organisation
Category_id, Organisation_id
```

So my query becomes something like this-

```
SELECT * FROM category c 
INNER JOIN category_organisation co ON co.category_id = c.category_id 
AND co.organisation_id = 'LOGGED_IN_USERs_ORGANISATION_ID'
```

If I were to add an exception i.e. allow some users too then I have this table

```
Category_user
Category_id, User_id
```

My questions are -

1. How do I do an OR search here so that the query returns the categories which belong to either to a given organisation id or to given user id
2. I want similar restriction for `Discussions` table. So I created ..

   Discussions

   Discussion_id, discussion_title

   Discussion_Users

   Discussion_Id, User_id

   Discussion_Organisations

   Discussion_Id, Organisation_id

As you can see I have to create similar tables - do you think I could achieve it one main permissions table for all these products, categories, or anyother new tables?

Comment: Read more about SQL JOINS and many-to-many, one-to-many, one-to-one relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM category c 
INNER JOIN category_organisation co ON co.category_id = c.category_id 
AND co.organisation_id = 'LOGGED_IN_USERs_ORGANISATION_ID' OR c.category_id IN( SELECT Category_user.Category_id FROM Category_user WHERE Category_user.User_id = 'LOGGED_IN_USERs_ORGANISATION_ID')
```